# cannot print and listen at the same time

Tags: python, printing, speech-recognition, listen, pyttsx

I am writing a basic talking tom like code which listens to the person and repeats its audio along side i want it to display the text which the speaker has spoken.
the problem I'm facing is i am not able to use the print and listen command simultaneously. 
I need to speak the phrase twice i.e, once for printing it on screen and other time for repeating it. 
I want to figure it these both things to happen only at once i.e, the audio should be repeated and displayed at the same time without me repeating the phrase twice.

```
import speech_recognition
import pyttsx

speech_engine = pyttsx.init() 
speech_engine.setProperty('rate', 150)

def speak(text):
    speech_engine.say(text)
    speech_engine.runAndWait()

recognizer = speech_recognition.Recognizer()

def listen():
    with speech_recognition.Microphone() as source:
        recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
        audio = recognizer.listen(source)

try:

        return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)      
except speech_recognition.UnknownValueError:
    print("Could not understand audio")
except speech_recognition.RequestError as e:
    print("Recog Error; {0}".format(e))

return ""

speak("Say something!")
print (listen())
speak("I heard you say " + listen())
```

Answer (score 2):

```
speak("Say something!")
text = listen()
speak("I heard you say " + text)
```

Comment: thats not working pal :( 
its only repeating the phrase but not displaying it

Comment: put a `print(text)` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Write:

```
print(audio)
```

Under:

```
return recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
```

Comment: still the same result :/